# Using Nginx Module ngx_http_keyval_module

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

How can we use **keyval** that is part of Module ngx_http_keyval_module in **nginx.conf** file as defined in https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/blacklisting-ip-addresses/

Do we need to import some module in some way.

Following is my configuration on ngnix

```
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

keyval_zone zone=one:1m state=one.keyval;
keyval $remote_addr $target zone=one;

server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost
    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
include servers/*;
```

}

And i get an following error when i start nginx :-

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "keyval_zone"
```

Comment: You have the paid version of `nginx` right ? If yes run `nginx -V` and check the modules are enabled.

Comment: /etc/nginx # nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.13.8
built by gcc 6.2.1 20160822 (Alpine 6.2.1) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
TLS SNI support enabled

I dont think i have paid version.  Is there an alternate solution i can use?

Comment: what about the `configure arguments:...` part of the output of the command?

Comment: its too long for this comment. but i did not find this module any where in whole installation.

Comment: well if is not listed most probably nginx isn't compiled with it. Check here how to add modules https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/compiling/ although the particular one is only available in the paid version so I don't really know how you can add it avoiding licensing problems. I would open a ticket for that. Plus its better to edit your question for this output.

Comment: **--with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-ipv6 --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module **

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170622/discussion-between-sunder-and-zochamx).